# Highlight substring which can contain own extrac characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to create function, that highlights my searched substring. For example, I have string "123456789" and I am search for substring "234". It's easy, only what I need is to create function:

```
str_replace('234', '123456789', '<b>234</b>');
```

But string can contains four (only this four) special characters (" ", "(", ")", "-") which I need to jump over.

So I can have string "12 3(456)78-9)" and I still need to highlight searched "234", so final string needs to look like

```
"1<b>2 3(4</b>56)78-9)"
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do this?

EDIT: string and substring can contains any character, not only numbers for example string: "Poly(amide 610)" and searched word can be "polyamide6" - highlighted will be "Poly(amide 6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a subpattern that describe characters you want to skip between each character of the target string:

```
$str = '12 3(456)78-9)';
$needle = '234';
$neutral = '[ ()-]*';

$pattern = '/' . implode($neutral, array_map(preg_quote, str_split($needle))) . '/iu';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

Comment: sry for inaccuracy, string and substring can contains any character,not only numbers

Comment: @SilentCry: this is only an example, you must choose/build your own `$neutral` subpattern (depending of your own criterae). In your case you can use: `[ ()-]*` instead.

Comment: Yes, but characters can be 0-9, aA-zZ, russian characters, greek characters an much more, it can be very hard to create $neutral pattern. I think that easier solution must exists.

Comment: @SilentCry: You must be able to define exactly what characters you want to skip (or what characters you want to preserve), otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: only last thing, it works great but... like on "edit" in my post, your code not working, when I'm searching with other letter-case than string contains for example "polyamide6" on "Poly(amide 610)" not working because of p/P difference :(

Comment: @SilentCry: Use the i modifier to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: Great, that's all. Thank you MASTER :-)